# Show form data to user in custom confirmation page

Tags: sitecore-forms

We use Sitecore 9.3 with JSS/React. I am new to Sitecore and still learning how to connect all the pieces between server side and client side code.

How can I send the user to a custom confirmation page after submitting a Sitecore Form using a custom Submit Action? This custom confirmation page should fetch form data using a submission ID. None of the form data can be sent via a query string like the out-of-the-box submit action. This means "Redirect URL" and "Redirect to Page" Submit Actions will not work for my use case.

At this point, I have a working Submit Action that logs form input values and the form ID. But I don't understand how to make this data available client side. Do I need a content resolver? How do I connect that to a Submit Action? How do I connect a content resolver to a React component?

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score -1):

If the purpose here is only to show the data which was already filled, you can use following options

1. Local Storage - The moment form is submitted, you can store the data in local storage, you can store full JSON object in it and on confirmation page you can read that local storage and display those data.
2. If you need to query some data and show additional fields, You can simply make one .fetch call and pass the submission id and write your api code which returns you the json data from that submission id

your API function can return that value and you can display that in your confirmation page, in this way, you will have server side api call and everything will work

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I still do not understand how to expose backend data so that client-side code can access it. How can I make data from the submit action available to the confirmation page?

Comment: For context, my background is in PHP, and code abstraction is carried out differently there. I'm still learning the C#/Sitecore paradigm.